# History API - rewriting URL with several slashes?

Tags: html, browser-history, pushstate, history.js

I'm using HTML5's History API (through History.js) to dynamically rewrite URLs. I would like them to be the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/example/article/page
```

where both 'article' and 'page' are set by the History API.

However, this doesn't quite work as expected, as the `pushState` or `replaceState` provided by History.js only seem to work on the part of the URL which is after the last slash.

A quick example: if I'm at `http://www.example.com/example/` and do `pushState('Article-Title/1')`, the url becomes `http://www.example.com/example/Article-Title/1`. Now I can change the page number with `pushState('2')`, but I have no way of changing the `Article-Title` part, which is what I'm after. `window.location.href`, which is used in Ben Lupton's [example](https://gist.github.com/854622), can change the URL, but it also causes a "hard" redirect.

I suppose that this constraint is in place in order to prevent XSS; however, it bothers me greatly. Is there a reasonable way around it?

Answer (score 4):

Found it: the URL I'm pushing has to start with a forward slash. That's all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use relative URLS : `../../Another-Section/1`